# How to see sources of .NET Core framework in visual studio 2015

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, asp.net-core, .net-core

Let me explain in more details what I mean. When I was programming on java using eclipse I could attach sources of java to IDE and whenever I ctrl+clicked on some built in class it showed me it's source code not just interface. Is this possible with visual studio 2015 and .NET Core framework? At least there are sources on github, but is there a way to see them in visual studio?

Comment: If I understand correctly, you'd like to see the implementation of a class, rather than just the Interface. There is a Visual Studio extension in the Visual Studio MarketPlace name GoToImplementation. I believe it will do what you're asking for.

Comment: the problem here is that vs can't find a symbol and this is because (I believe) there is no source code attached

Answer (score 1):

When you create an ASP.NET Core project you are using .NET Core libraries which are already compiled. That's why you don't have access to the source code. Otherwise when you compile your project it means Visual Studio would have to compile the .NET Core framework as well. What a loss of time...

DLLs are located for example under

> C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\1.0.0-preview2-003131

As you can see, no source code here

Comment: well, I know the reason why I can't see the source code. The question is how to resolve the problem

Comment: Then same answer as @jcmontx download the source from GitHub. I beleive with Java, IDE like IntelliJ or Eclipse have an under de hood feature that enables you to navigate to the source but when you debug, the compiled assemblies are actually used. Otherwise I don't see how that would be possible without compiling them to run your program. But as I know there is no such thing with .NET

Comment: yep, the only thing possible is to add source files in global.json to projects array. though it works for asp.net core only, couldn't make it work with .net core yet unfortunately

Comment: and yes, java ides are using compiled assemblies (if to speak the .net terms) but when navigating in code they sow you the source so you can see inner implementation which is very helpful while learning

Answer (score 1):

You could download the source code from [Github](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx), add all the projects to your solution, configure the [build pipeline](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/tree/master/buildpipeline) and compile the whole framework everytime you have to run your solution.

Comment: hm... but is it somehow possible to include sources but not compile them every time? the nice approach has eclipse and I believe Intellidea from jetbrains when you can have a copiled .jar and the sources of the .jar along it. and when you want to see the implementation you don't just see the public interface but whole implementation source

Comment: Giving it a second thought, you probably won't have to compile it unless you make changes in the code. While building, it skips projects which are up to date.